# curl output for ISP different when using VPN

Tags: curl, vpn, echo, macos

I'm doing a curl command to grab my ISP details. The problem is that the ISP details are different when connected to my company VPN.

```
VPN disabled:
isp=`curl -s ipinfo.io/org`
echo: $isp
Comcast Cable Communications, LLC

VPN enabled, curl command re-ran... 
Output:
(Company VPN name)
```

Is there an alternate method to grab my ISP details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're routing through a VPN provider, that VPN provider effectively *is* your internet service provider.  That's the entire point.  Your provider with such tools is typically determined by checking the owner of the IP from which your HTTP request egressed.  If you want to get the information about your physical connection to the internet, look at your *router* to get its WAN IP address, and use a tool such as `whois` to find the owner of that IP address.

Comment: I understand. The entire point of tunneled traffic. Whois gives the same info, but I have my answer. Thank you!